# How to filter ValueSet by property value?

Tags: hapi-fhir

I'm trying to use FHIR terminology for own terminology service. I created CodySystem/ValueSet pair:

```
{
    "resourceType": "CodeSystem",
    "url": "<my host>/gender-codesystem",
    "version": "1",
    "content": "complete",
    "property": [
        {
            "code": "laboratory_type",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "concept": [
        {
            "code": "male",
            "display": "Male",
            "property": [
                {
                    "code": "laboratory_type",
                    "valueString": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "female",
            "display": "Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "resourceType": "ValueSet",
    "url": "<my host>/gender",
    "compose": {
        "include": [
            {
                "system": "<my host>/gender-codesystem",
                "version": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In ValueSet/$expand?url=.../gender I see section 'expansion.contains' with all concepts. They have 'code' and 'display', but do not have information about additional property 'laboratory_type'.

- hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter
- hapi-fhir 6.4.0

1. How to to filter concepts in ValueSet by additional property?
2. How to get additional property value in ValueSet/$expand result?

Answer (score 1):

In FHIR, when you expand a ValueSet using the **$expand** operation, the resulting expansion contains the basic information about the concepts, including their code and display. However, additional properties defined in the CodeSystem are not automatically included in the expansion by default.

To filter concepts in a ValueSet based on additional properties, you can use the **$filter** parameter in the **$expand** operation. The **$filter** parameter allows you to specify criteria for filtering the concepts based on their properties.

To include the additional property "laboratory_type" in the expansion result, you need to explicitly request it by using the **_include** parameter in the **$expand** operation. You can specify the additional property's code ("laboratory_type" in this case) in the **_include** parameter to include it in the expansion result.

Here's an example of how you can use the $expand operation with the _filter and _include parameters to filter concepts and include additional properties in the expansion result:

GET *[base]/ValueSet/$expand?url=/gender&filter=laboratory_type=1&_include=ValueSet:compose.include.concept.property*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34714959)